# EXPLAIN - 'float' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, loops, methods

```py
fname=open('C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\mbox-short.txt','r')
count=0
val=0.000
for num in fname:
    if num.startswith('X-DSPAM-Confidence:'):
        count=count+1
        for i in num:
            val[i]=num[19:25]          #error
            print(i,val)
```

If I do not assign val=0.000, then this error shows up: `name 'val' is not defined`.
That is because of local declaration maybe and not globally (that's my perception) so I end up assigning value to 'val'.

Comment: You cannot index `val` if it is a float, or if it is undefined. Currently this code does not seem to make much sense at all. In your loop `i` is just a single character string, so using that as an index into val will not work unless you turn val into `dict`.

Comment: It's easier to give good advice if you explain in your question what you want the code to do. It's a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

you can not operate iteration over a number, but you can over an array
if you don't need `val` out of the loop just

```
for num in fname:
    if num.startswith('X-DSPAM-Confidence:'):
        count=count+1
        for i in num:
            print(i, num[19:25])
```

if you want an map do:

```
count=0
val={}
for num in fname:
    if num.startswith('X-DSPAM-Confidence:'):
        count=count+1
        for i in num:
            val[i]=num[19:25]         
            print(i, val[i])
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that but then it shows this error:                                                    `val[i]=num[19:25]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str `

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting -- see at the end of answer -- a revised code based on a reasonable guess at what you might be trying to achieve (although not completely clear in the question).

This code will open the file and loop over lines, and for those which start with `'X-DSPAM-Confidence:'` it will extract the relevant substring and it into a floating point value and print it, as well as store it in a list called `values`.

The variable you called `num` appears to be intended to contain a string.  This is syntactically valid but probably not helpful to the reader to have a name that suggests a different purpose, so it is renamed here as `line`.

There is a similar issue in your code with the variable called `fname` whose name suggests that it would contain the name of the file, but in fact contains the file handle returned by the `open` function.  The revised code uses this variable to contain the name itself; the actual filehandle does not need to be stored in a variable in this case.

The specific error that you were getting was to try to index a float called `val`.  A float is not a data type that can be used in that way (item assignment), and in this particular case, you probably meant to use a list.  I have used a list in the suggested code called `values`.  Elements of this can be assigned to using for example `values[i] = value`.  However, this can only be used to change the contents of an existing element of the list, not to change the length of the list.  To add another element onto the list inside the loop, you would instead call the `append` method of your `values` list, passing a parameter which is the item that you want to append to the list (which I called `value`).

This code makes the assumption that the data in the string `line[19:25]` can be converted into a float.  If that is not the case (e.g. it consists of alphabetical characters), then the code would report an error and stop.  How to deal with that error is probably out of scope for this question, but it can be done if needed.

A final minor comment: because the file path contains `\` characters, it is necessary to put an `r` immediately before the open quotes on the first line.  This is to prevent the `\` character from having a special meaning as an escape character in string processing.

```
fname = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\mbox-short.txt'
count = 0
values = []
for line in open(fname, 'r'):
    if line.startswith('X-DSPAM-Confidence:'):
        count = count + 1
        value = float(line[19:25])
        values.append(value)
        print(count, value)
```